# Как правильно подключить BarCode (Генератор штрих-кода)

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, qrcode, barcode

Сейчас сижу в проекте .NetFramework C++

Скачал Zen.Barcode.Rendering.Framework.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил через Manage NuGet. Установка прошла успешно.

Пытаюсь написать ключевое слово `Zen`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я допускаю ошибку? Помогите пожалуйста! Уже 3 час сижу.

Comment: Как я понимаю, Вы работаете с managed кодом. Так что во первых, нужен какой то аналог using  из C#. Пример на C#: https://github.com/dementeddevil/BarcodeRenderingFramework/blob/master/src/SampleSite/Default.aspx.cs

Comment: спасибо. Буду пытаться

Comment: Вполне возможно, проще написать hello world (применительно к баркодам) на C#, а потом уже перейти на managed C++

Comment: На C# эту задачу сделать очень легко)))
Мне буквально нужно нарисовать штрих-код из полученного id_product (13 чисел из БД). И всё... Хотел решить задачу красиво с картинкой, но....Чувствую, что пока опыт не позволяет))) НО ГЛАВНОЕ НЕ СДАВАТЬСЯ!!!